# Problem with multi level pop out menu in IE8

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I've made a multi level pop out menu from [this](http://www.stunicholls.com/menu/pro_dropdown_2.html) tutorial, [here's the page](http://www.teamworksdesign.com/clients/match/) I'm working on.

It's working perfectly fine in all browsers bar IE8, the 3rd tier just hides behind the second tier.

Can anyone see what the problem is?

Here's the code:

```
    <div id="menu">
    <div id="menu-edge"></div>   

<ul id="nav">
    <li class="top"><a class="top_link" href="http://www.match.ac.uk">Home</a></li>
    <li class="top"><a class="top_link" href="/about.php">About</a>
        <ul class="sub" style="margin-left:0px;">
            <li><a class="fly" href="/theteam.php">The Team</a>
                <ul class="sub-popout">
                    <li><a href="/researchers.php">Researchers</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/management.php">Management</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/investigators.php">Investigators</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/students.php">PhD Students</a></li>                                                            
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="/vision.php">Our Vision</a></li>
            <li><a href="/strategy.php">Strategy</a></li>
            <li><a href="/achievements.php">Achievements</a></li>
            <li><a href="/literature.php">Literature</a></li>
        </ul>    
    </li>
    <li class="top"><a class="top_link" href="/membership.php">Membership</a>
        <ul class="sub" style="margin-left:0px;">
            <li><a href="/level1.php">Level 1 - Micro</a></li>
            <li><a href="/level2.php">Level 2 - SME/Division</a></li>            
            <li><a href="/level3.php">Level 3 - Large</a></li>
            <li><a href="/level1.php">Level 4 - Macro</a></li>
            <li><a href="/additional.php">Additional Services</a></li>                        
        </ul>
    <li class="top"><a class="top_link" href="/research.php">Research</a>
        <ul class="sub" style="margin-left:0px;">
            <li><a href="/projecti.php">Project I - Tools for Industry</a></li>
            <li><a href="/projectii.php">Project II - Economic Evaluation</a></li>    
            <li><a href="/projectiii.php">Project III - User Needs</a></li>
            <li><a href="/projectiv.php">Project IV - Implementation Issues</a></li>
        </ul>                
    <li class="top"><a class="top_link" href="/publications.php">Publications</a>
        <ul class="sub" style="margin-left:0px;">
            <li><a href="/2011.php">2011</a></li>
            <li><a href="/2010.php">2010</a></li>
            <li><a href="/2009.php">2009</a></li>
            <li><a href="/2008.php">2008</a></li>
            <li><a href="/2007.php">2007</a></li>
            <li><a href="/2006.php">2006</a></li>
            <li><a href="/2005.php">2005</a></li>
            <li><a href="/2004.php">2004</a></li>
            <li><a href="/deliverables.php">Deliverables</a></li>
            <li><a href="/innovative-manufacturing.php">Innovative Manufacturing</a></li>                                                                                                                    
        </ul>
    <li class="top"><a class="top_link" href="/news-events.php">News &amp; Events</a>
        <ul class="sub" style="margin-left:0px;">
            <li><a href="/news.php">News</a></li>
            <li><a href="/events.php">Events</a></li>
            <li><a href="/training.php">Training &amp; Workshops</a></li>
        </ul>                                
    <li class="top"><a class="top_link" href="/partners.php">Partners</a>
    <li class="top"><a class="top_link" href="/contact.php">Contact Us</a>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#menu {
    float:right;
    height:33px;
    background-color:#00B1E8;
    margin-top:14px;
    width:749px;
    }


#nav {
    padding:5px 0 0 0;
    margin:0 0 0 79px;
    list-style:none;
    height:27px;
    background-color:#00B1E8;
    position:relative;
    z-index:500;
    font-size:13px;
    }
#nav li.top {display:block; float:left; height:33px;}

a.no-sub {
    color:#ffffff;
    display:block; float:left; height:33px; text-decoration:none; margin-right: 20px; cursor:pointer;
    }

a.no-sub:hover {
    color:#1D71B8;
    display:block; float:left; height:33px; text-decoration:none; margin-right: 20px; cursor:pointer;
    }   

#nav li a.top_link {display:block; float:left; height:33px; color:#fff; text-decoration:none; margin-right: 20px; cursor:pointer;}
#nav li a.top_link span {float:left; display:block; padding:0 24px 0 12px; height:35px; background: url(three_0.gif) right top no-repeat;}
#nav li a.top_link span.down {float:left; display:block; padding:0 24px 0 12px; height:35px; background: url(three_0a.gif) no-repeat right top;}

#nav li:hover a.top_link {color:#1D71B8;}
#nav li:hover a.top_link span {background:url(three_1.gif) no-repeat right top;}
#nav li:hover a.top_link span.down {background:url(three_1a.gif) no-repeat right top;}

/* Default list styling */

#nav li:hover {position:relative; z-index:200;}

#nav li:hover ul.sub {
    left:1px;
    top:26px;
    padding:3px;
    white-space:nowrap;
    width:250px;
    height:auto;
    z-index:300;
    background:transparent;
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr=#00B1E8,endColorStr=#00B1E8);
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#00B1E8,endColorstr=#00B1E8)";
    zoom: 1;
    background-color: rgba(54, 169, 225, 0.8);  
    }

#nav li:hover ul.sub li
{display:block; height:20px; position:relative; float:left; width:250px; font-weight:normal;}

#nav li:hover ul.sub li a {
    display:block;
    height:18px;
    width:250px;
    line-height:18px;
    text-indent:5px;
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
    }

#nav li ul.sub li a.fly
{background-color:#0e71b8;}
#nav li:hover ul.sub li a:hover 
{background-color:#0e71b8;}
#nav li:hover ul.sub li a.fly:hover
{background-color:#0e71b8;}


#nav li:hover li:hover ul,
#nav li:hover li:hover li:hover ul,
#nav li:hover li:hover li:hover li:hover ul,
#nav li:hover li:hover li:hover li:hover li:hover ul
{left:251px;
top:-3px; 
background:transparent;
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr=#00B1E8,endColorStr=#00B1E8);
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#00B1E8,endColorstr=#00B1E8)";
    zoom: 1;
    background-color: rgba(54, 169, 225, 0.8); padding:3px; white-space:nowrap; width:250px; z-index:400; height:auto;}

#nav ul, 
#nav li:hover ul ul,
#nav li:hover li:hover ul ul,
#nav li:hover li:hover li:hover ul ul,
#nav li:hover li:hover li:hover li:hover ul ul
{position:absolute; left:-9999px; top:-9999px; width:0; height:0; margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none;}

#nav li:hover li:hover a.fly,
#nav li:hover li:hover li:hover a.fly,
#nav li:hover li:hover li:hover li:hover a.fly,
#nav li:hover li:hover li:hover li:hover li:hover a.fly
{background-color:#0e71b8; color:#fff; border-color:#fff;} 

#nav li:hover li:hover li a.fly,
#nav li:hover li:hover li:hover li a.fly,
#nav li:hover li:hover li:hover li:hover li a.fly
{background:#bbd37e url(arrow.gif) 80px 6px no-repeat; color:#000; border-color:#bbd37e;}
```

Here's the JS:

```
stuHover = function() {
    var cssRule;
    var newSelector;
    for (var i = 0; i < document.styleSheets.length; i++)
        for (var x = 0; x < document.styleSheets[i].rules.length ; x++)
            {
            cssRule = document.styleSheets[i].rules[x];
            if (cssRule.selectorText.indexOf("LI:hover") != -1)
            {
                 newSelector = cssRule.selectorText.replace(/LI:hover/gi, "LI.iehover");
                document.styleSheets[i].addRule(newSelector , cssRule.style.cssText);
            }
        }
    var getElm = document.getElementById("nav").getElementsByTagName("LI");
    for (var i=0; i<getElm.length; i++) {
        getElm[i].onmouseover=function() {
            this.className+=" iehover";
        }
        getElm[i].onmouseout=function() {
            this.className=this.className.replace(new RegExp(" iehover\\b"), "");
        }
    }
}
if (window.attachEvent) window.attachEvent("onload", stuHover);
```

Comment: seems to be working for me. Have you fixed it?

Comment: @GaryRyan Was it on IE8 that you tried it? That's the only browser that's not working.

Comment: Yes, sorry, your right. I copied and pasted the wrong site over...my bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the top of your HTML:

```
<!-- header -->
<!-- SEO elements to be edited per page, enter your keywords between the "" -->
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

Those comments at the top are making IE use [Quirks Mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode#Triggering_different_rendering_modes).

Make sure `<!DOCTYPE html ..` is the very first line, and IE will use Standards Mode and your problem will probably be resolved.

---

In your CSS, inside `#nav li:hover ul.sub`, you need to remove:

```
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr=#00B1E8,endColorStr=#00B1E8);
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#00B1E8,endColorstr=#00B1E8)";
```

using those causes an `overflow: hidden`-esque effect, and that's why your submenus can't be seen.

Comment: Just took the comments out and it didn't make any difference to the menu.

Comment: I've updated my answer. It's not a complete solution, but it's why you can't see the second-level submenus.

Comment: Thanks @thirtydot, it's working but thrown up another problem by removing that css. I have a transparent background that works for all other browsers and that was a fix for IE, now it doesn't have a background to it. Are there any ways to get it to appear again for IE (a solid one will do) but show transparency for all other browsers?

Comment: Try `background: #??????; background: rgba(?,?,?,?);`. IE does not support `rgba`, so it will ignore the second `background`. Browsers that support `rgba` (including IE *9*) will use the second `background`.

Comment: thanks for the efforts. Solved it with a transparent png. in the end. I thought the same with adding in two background styles but it doesn't work. Anyways, got there in the end, thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

```
Multilevel CSS Menu<br>
Demo <a href="www.mremind.com">Here</a><br>
<h2>Css For Menu</h2>
<p>
/**
* MAIN NAVIGATION
**/
#mainNav {`enter code here`

    height:60px;
    margin: 0 auto;

    padding-left: 15px;
    width:1000px;
    vertical-align: middle;

    }


#mainNav  ul{
    list-style-type:block;
    list-style-image:none;
    background:red;

    margin: 0;
    padding-right: 0px;

    padding-left: 0px;

    line-height: 100%;
    -khtml-border: 1px solid #BFDBD7;



    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0, .4);

    vertical-align: middle;
    }




/************************************** Main Navigation boxes ******************************************************/
#mainNav ul li.navItems{
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
    width:94px;
    height:60px;
    border-left:solid 1px #D7D7D7;

    }
#mainNav ul li.navItems:hover{

    background:#034693;
    }
#mainNav ul li.navItems:current{

    }   
#mainNav ul li.navItems > a{
    width:94px;
    height:60px;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    color:#4D4D4D;
    display:block;
    line-height:5.5em;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
    }
#mainNav ul li.navItems a:hover{
    color:#FFF;
    }

#mainNav ul li.navItems:hover a{
    color:#FFF;  /*keeps main nav text white upon rollover*/
    }
#mainNav ul li.navItems:hover ul a{
    color:#4D4D4D;  /*stops sublinks from being white */
    }






/* Dropdown List */

#mainNav ul li.navItems ul{
    background:#FAFAFA;
    border:1px solid #CCC;
    list-style:none;
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
    width:250px;

    z-index:100;
    }

    #mainNav ul li.navItems ul li
    {

        padding: 10px 0;
        font-size: 13px;
        line-height: 1.5em !important;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
        white-space: nowrap;
        text-align: left;

    }
    #mainNav ul li.navItems ul li a{

    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 1.5em !important;
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-left:5px;

    }
#mainNav ul li.navItems:hover ul li > a:hover{
    background:#034693;
    color:#FFF;
    }


    #mainNav ul li.navItems:hover ul li:hover{
    background:#034693;
    color:#FFF;
    }

    #mainNav ul li.navItems:hover ul li:hover > a{
    background:#034693;
    color:#FFF;
    }

#mainNav  ul li.navItems:hover  ul.secondul{
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    }






/************************************** Sub Menu boxes ******************************************************/  





    #mainNav  ul.secondul li.MarketingLI:hover ul
    {

    display:block;
    position:absolute;


    }




    #mainNav  ul.secondul li.MarketingLI ul{
    width:200px;

    padding:0;
    font-size:13px;
    line-height:1.5em !important;
    border-bottom:1px solid #CCC;
    white-space:nowrap;
    text-align:left;
    display:none;
    top:0;
    margin-left:100%;

    }
</p><br>
<br>
<h2>HTML</h2><br>
<p>
<div id="mainNav">
            <ul >

                <li class="navItems"><a href=""></a> </li>
                <li class="navItems" ><a class="first" href="#"></a>


                 <ul class="secondul">
                        <li class="MarketingLI"><a class="first" href=""></a>

                        <ul >
                            <li ><a href="">2nd Level 1</a>
                            </li>

                             <li ><a href="">2nd Level 1</a>
                            </li>

                            <li ><a href="">2nd Level 1</a>
                            </li>

                        </ul>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href=""></a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#"></a></li>

                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="navItems"><a href=""></a>
                </li>

                <li class="navItems"><a href=""></a></li>
                <li class="navItems"><a href=""></a> </li>
                <li class="navItems"><a href=""></a> </li>
            </ul>
            <!--mainNav-->
        </div>
</p>
```

Comment: You should describe your answer rather than just posting a large block of code.